# Testing Hapi routes with Jest hangs if the test fails

Tags: node.js, jestjs, hapi.js

I'm working on something where I'm using Hapi as a web server for a REST API, and I'm using Jest for unit testing. I've just set it up to test the REST routes themselves - by using `server.inject` on the created Hapi server.

This works fantastically, as long as the tests pass. If the tests fail then everything runs to completion but the process doesn't terminate.

For reference, my test looks like this:

```
// @flow

import createServer from '../server';

describe('Hapi Healthchecks', () => {
    let server;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        server = await createServer();
    });

    test('Hapi Healthchecks respond correctly', async () => {
        const response = await server.inject({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/health',
        });

        expect.assertions(1);
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
});
```

`createServer` returns the result of `Glue.compose`, so it's a configured but not-yet-started Hapi server. I don't start the server in the tests - there's no need - and so there's no call to `server.stop()`. However, if I add either or both of those in then it makes no difference.

As long as the test passes the assertion then everything is fine. If the test fails for any reason then everything else still runs - including `afterEach` and `afterAll` calls, but the process simply fails to exit.

Any suggestions for what I'm missing to get this working correctly?

Comment: I think "expect.assertions(1);" should be put before your "await"-code. Otherwise if an error is thrown it will be ignored. Not sure if that helps you with your problem though.

Comment: Hei, look this answer for tips on how to show correct messages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874414/yarn-test-hangs-when-one-more-tests-file-is-added/68643113#68643113

Answer (score 0):

You have to use in `beforeAll` method like

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  server = await createServer();
  server.start();
});
afterAll(async() => {
  await server.stop();
})
```

you can use `beforeAll` or `beforeEach` based on your use case. The above code will start and stop the server before and after the test. I think this will solve the problem.