# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON with Jest + Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, jestjs

Using the jest-preset-angular to perform the unit test, but got an warning as `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` not sure what causing the error, due to this the application is stuck and not running the other unit test.

```
PASS  src/app/pages/result/result-filter/result-filter.component.spec.ts (6.251 s)
 PASS  src/app/pages/result/search-navigation/search-navigation.component.spec.ts
 PASS  src/app/pages/result/filter-modal/filter-modal.component.spec.ts (5.699 s)
 PASS  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
 PASS  src/app/pages/test-type/test-type.component.spec.ts (12.857 s)
(node:3280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'element' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'componentProvider' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'parent' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at writeChannelMessage (internal/child_process/serialization.js:117:20)
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:808:17)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:706:19)
    at reportSuccess (/Users/macbook/Projects/Playtime Projects/IDP/Idp.Bx.Ui/idp/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:67:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3280) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:3281) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'element' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'componentProvider' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'parent' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at writeChannelMessage (internal/child_process/serialization.js:117:20)
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:808:17)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:706:19)
    at reportSuccess (/Users/macbook/Projects/Playtime Projects/IDP/Idp.Bx.Ui/idp/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:67:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3281) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3281) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:3279) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'element' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'componentProvider' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'parent' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at writeChannelMessage (internal/child_process/serialization.js:117:20)
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:808:17)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:706:19)
    at reportSuccess (/Users/macbook/Projects/Playtime Projects/IDP/Idp.Bx.Ui/idp/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:67:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3279) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3279) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

 RUNS  src/app/pages/location/location.component.spec.ts
 RUNS  src/app/pages/signup/signup.component.spec.ts
 RUNS  src/app/pages/login/login.component.spec.ts

Test Suites: 10 passed, 10 of 20 total
Tests:       16 passed, 16 total
Snapshots:   1 obsolete, 5 passed, 5 total
Time:        2180 s
```

I am not sure how to run the node --trace-warnings. Looks like it a serialization issue, even it is just a warning but not sure where is the issue. Is there any better way to find the exception

Comment: I have a similar issue and I believe in my case it's related with the fact that I am doing some async work in ngOnInit.

Comment: In my case its an observable (say, this.observeMe$) in ngOnInit function being awaited in the html file (say, {{ observeMe | async }})

I changed it to this.observeMe.subscribe(...) to overcome this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format shows how to use JSON to a circular so it at least should solve your error

Answer (score 118):

Run jest with `--detectOpenHandles`. This will show you what is actually wrong with your test spec. For me, there were missing Angular Material imports and service mocks. You may be prompted to add the `BrowserAnimationsModule`, as Nambi alluded to in his answer

package.json:

```
"test": "jest --detectOpenHandles"
```

Answer (score 21):

This message usually appears, if there is an error, that does not resolve into a standard exception.

As mentioned by @JamesBarret using jests `detect open handle` feature will provide you with a nice error message, telling you what the real problem behind this message is.

The handle  `--detectOpenHandles` mentioned in the other message is deprecated though and was replaced with `--detect-open-handles`.

You can just use: (on your cli)

```
jest --detect-open-handles
```

Or in a package.json file:

```
"test": "jest --detect-open-handles"
```

Or as it was in my case an angular test:

```
ng test --detect-open-handles
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding my answer to help someone if missed.
In my case i have missed to import

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Able to find the issue only when running one of the test case in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the async operation, so writing the test case with below, solve the issue for me

```
describe('DateSelectionComponent', () => {
  let component: DateSelectionComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DateSelectionComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DateSelectionComponent, SafePipe],
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        NgReduxTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: PageAPIActions, useValue: { setPageState() { } }
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DateSelectionComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    // Don't use Object.defineProperty when assigning value to class properties
    component.page$ = of('value');
    component.page = { destination: 'value' };
    component.startDate = new NgbDate(2019, 2, 27);
    component.minDate = new NgbDate(2019, 2, 27);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Should Match Snapshot', () => {
     expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement).toMatchSnapshot()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the cryptic error was triggered by not importing `HttpClientModule` into the test file. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64503418/4822174).

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue when running jest with `--watch`. Removing `--watch` stopped the error.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the error is due to some async operation being done. Try wrapping your unit test inside a waitForAsync function.